# 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback

Tags: c, opengl, exception, visual-studio-2015, unhandled

I am encountering the error '0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback', when I run the OpenGL code. Th debugger indicates that the error occurs here:

[image: Debugger Screen]

The function where the error occurs and calling functions are given below.

Could you please help me identify the cause for this error.

```
double maxDistance(Point_2D* bez, int deg)
{
int i;
double maxheight;
double height[30];

// Computing baseline vector and its magnitude
Point_2D baselineVector;
baselineVector.x = bez[deg].x - bez[0].x;
baselineVector.y = bez[deg].y - bez[0].y;
double baselineMag = sqrt((baselineVector.x*baselineVector.x) + (baselineVector.y*baselineVector.y));

double crossprod[3];

double crossprodMag;

// Computing height of a intermediate control points from baseline
Point_2D cpVector; // Vector from first control point to intermediate control point
for (i = 1; i < deg; i++)
{
    cpVector.x = bez[i].x - bez[0].x;
    cpVector.y = bez[i].y - bez[0].y;

    // Computing cross product of baseline vector and control point vector
    //z coordinates of baseline and control point vectors are 0
    crossprod[0] = ((baselineVector.y * 0) - (0 * cpVector.y));
    crossprod[1] = -((baselineVector.x * 0) - (0 * cpVector.x));
    crossprod[2] = ((baselineVector.x * cpVector.y) - (baselineVector.y * cpVector.x));
    crossprodMag = sqrt((crossprod[0] * crossprod[0]) + (crossprod[1] * crossprod[1]) + (crossprod[2] * crossprod[2]));
    height[i] = crossprodMag / baselineMag;
}

// Finding maximum height of a control point from baseline
maxheight = height[0];
for (i = 0; i < deg; i++)
{
    if (maxheight < height[i])
        maxheight = height[i];
}


return maxheight;
}
void plotBezier(Point_2D* bez, int deg)
{
Point_2D* leftBez= (Point_2D*)malloc((deg + 1)*sizeof(Point_2D));
Point_2D* rightBez=(Point_2D*)malloc((deg + 1)*sizeof(Point_2D));;
double height = maxDistance(bez, deg);
if (height < flat_thresh)
{
    drawLine(bez[0], bez[deg]);
    return;
}
else
{
    midSubdivideBezier(bez, deg, leftBez, rightBez);
    plotBezier(leftBez, deg);
    plotBezier(rightBez, deg);
}
free(leftBez);
free(rightBez);
 }



//============================================================
void adaptiveRender()
 {
Point_2D*  bez =(Point_2D*) malloc(30 * sizeof(Point_2D)); // assume the degree is not greater than 29.
int      i;

for (i = bcr.degree; i< bcr.deBoor_count; i++) // Determining segments between the kth knot and the (n+1)th knot
{
    if (!(fabs(bcr.knots[i] - bcr.knots[i + 1]) < 0.00001)) // No segment when adjacent knots are equal
    {
        extractBezier(bez, i);        // Extract the i-th Bezier curve
        plotBezier(bez, bcr.degree);   // Adaptively plot a Bezier curve 
    }
}
free(bez);
}
```

Comment: The `stack overflow` that's reported in your screenshot leads me to believe that your some function (or functions) is just calling itself over and over again forever (until memory runs out).

Comment: Thanks a ton turbulencetoo ! That hint really helped! :)

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this exact problem, but only on laptops with the intel+nvidia dual graphics cards. For me, it started occurring when I added a .def file with

```
HEAPSIZE  1024  
STACKSIZE 4096
```

Seems that these parameters are OK for discrete nvidia GPU drivers, but might have some trouble with the intel drivers. Removing those directives from the .def file fixed the Stack Overflow issue. Hope this helps the next guy.